# Ngrok service on Windows failed with Access is denied

Tags: windows, ngrok

I can not install Ngrok as a service on Windows.

```
.\ngrok.exe service install --config  C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local/ngrok/ngrok.yml

INFO[08-02|20:16:08] open config file                         path=C:\\Users\\dev\\AppData\\Local\\ngrok\\ngrok.yml err=nil
INFO[08-02|20:16:08] detect init system                       sys=windows-service
CRIT[08-02|20:16:08] install failed                           err="Failed to install ngrok: Access is denied."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PM from ngrok here. Usually installing ngrok as a service requires administrator privileges. I would suggest trying to run that command in a command prompt opened in administrator mode.